# Connecting to Biometrics Fingerprint Machine via Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, fingerprint

So I am trying to create this application where I can retrieve the data from different types of biometric fingerprint devices. Most, if not all of them, I think, does not have SDKs. A stand-alone app (the same as what I am trying to achieve) was provided together with these devices and I can connect to them via TCP/IP (`192.168.1.201:4370`). However, if I try to access it via sockets in Java, it refuses to connect.

Code:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.201", 4370);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while (true){
        line = in.readLine();
        if (line != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Where do you think should I go from here?

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure the IP and port are correct?

Comment: It says connection refused. Yes, both the IP and port are correct.

Comment: That means nothing listens to connections on that port in that IP.

Comment: I do understand that part, but how could that be? The application that was given by the manufacturer can connect to the device just right. With the same IP and port.

Comment: Are you sure it uses TCP? Try using packet capture tools like wireshark to find out what difference there is between the connection you're trying to make and the app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: You could check with these 2 steps;
1. Open CMD terminal (windows)  then type; ping 192.168.1.201 then press Enter Key.
If you receive reply with time intervals and packets received, then that's proof device with that IP is reachable on your network. Proceed to step 2 to confirm if port 4370 is open on that IP.

2. In your CMD terminal, you could open another one or use the previously opened one then type; telnet 192.168.1.201 4370 and press Enter key.
If you do not get 'Could not open connection to host, on port 4370. Connection failed ' then your PORT is open.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a connection listening port 4370 which you really dont need to do that. Becuase, the socket is already created by the biometric machine in the configured IP in the machine at the port 4370 (configured port). what you need to do is, just connect with the port.

For connecting with the port, find zkemkeeper.dll in the net, which provides the APIs to connect the machine. Find the relevant documents more information.

If you are looking for WEB API supported machines, go for CAMSUnit machines. CAMS provides the [WEB APIs](http://www.etscouncil.com/login?mailerResponse=true&orn=Quora&ts=25/02/2017&ornr=%22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607046/connecting-to-biometrics-fingerprint-machine-via-java-sockets%22&tpc=Stackoverflow&it=website&learnref=http://camsunit.com) for their biometric machines. It supports registering the callback URL which gets called every time new attendance gets registered.